# combine two lists with a join on a column

Tags: bash, join, bioinformatics

I'm trying to combine two lists, joining them by a common field suchs as ENST00000371026. I've tried the following but no luck.  What is the actual way to do it?

```
cat> gar1.txt <<EOF
ENST00000371026 ENSG00000152763
ENST00000371023 ENSG00000152763
ENST00000395250 ENSG00000152763
ENST00000309502 ENSG00000163485
ENST00000377464 ENSG00000142599
ENST00000400908 ENSG00000142599
ENST00000337907 ENSG00000142599
ENST00000400907 ENSG00000142599
ENST00000401087 ENSG00000179571
EOF

cat> gar2.txt <<EOF
DDX11L1 ENST00000371026
DDX11L9 ENST00000309502
DDX11L1 ENST00000371026
OR4F5   ENST00000377464
DQ597235        n/a
DQ599768        n/a
LOC388312       ENST00000401087
LOC100132287    ENST00000425496
LOC100132287    ENST00000425496
EOF

join -t"\t" -2 2 -1 1 gar1.txt gar2.txt
```

An example output would be:

```
DDX11L1 ENSG00000152763
DDX11L9 ENSG00000163485
OR4F5   ENSG00000142599
LOC388312       ENSG00000179571
LOC100132287    NONE
```

Comment: Combine them how?  Alternating lines?  Take the columns from gar2.txt and append each line to the first file?

Comment: I would like to use gar1 as an index.  Then replace the ENST values in gar2 with ENSG and have a list of unique ENSG values with the corresponding field 1 of gar2.txt

Comment: See my edited answer. (I repeated this here since I don't know whether the @ addressing will work with your short username.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
join -a 2 -t $'\t' -2 2 -1 1 -o 2.1 1.2 <(sort gar1.txt) <(sort -k 2,2 gar2.txt) | sed '/\t$/ s/$/NONE/' | uniq
```

It uses Bash process substitution (`<()`), but you could simply presort your files if you don't want to use that. Your version of `join` needs to have the `-o` option or you could use awk to process the output further. For the "n/a" lines it will print "NONE", but you could do this to eliminate them:

```
<(sort -k 2,2 gar2.txt | grep -v 'n/a$')
```

**Edit:**

This is the output I get without the `sed` and `uniq`:

```
DDX11L9 ENSG00000163485
DDX11L1 ENSG00000152763
DDX11L1 ENSG00000152763
OR4F5   ENSG00000142599
LOC388312       ENSG00000179571
LOC100132287
LOC100132287
DQ597235
DQ599768
```

And this is what I get with them:

```
DDX11L9 ENSG00000163485
DDX11L1 ENSG00000152763
OR4F5   ENSG00000142599
LOC388312       ENSG00000179571
LOC100132287    NONE
DQ597235        NONE
DQ599768        NONE
```

Adding the `grep`:

```
DDX11L9 ENSG00000163485
DDX11L1 ENSG00000152763
OR4F5   ENSG00000142599
LOC388312       ENSG00000179571
LOC100132287    NONE
```

which matches your example output except for the order. If you need to preserve the order it would be possible to do.

Comment: +1 helpful, however join -a 2 -t $'\t' -2 2 -1 1 -o 2.1 1.2 <(sort gar1.txt) <(sort -k 2,2 gar2.txt) seems to output a sorted gar2.txt rather than the expect output.  Did it work for you for the example files?